Why is 403 forbidden returned when logging into Spring Security?
I'm currently messing around with Spring Security. Now I made a crutch to check authorization, but it doesn’t work. Authentication is not forwarded to the controller. I've had classes like this.
CustomerFilter
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.equals("abc")) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication
                    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("dad","4343");

            System.out.println("yes");

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

UserDetailsServiceImpl
@Component
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("dad", "4343", new ArrayList<>());
    }
}

SecurityConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/dfsdfs").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

The problem is that for some reason it doesn’t authorize me. The controller does not output anything to stdout. That is, it does not allow access to a protected endpoint. help me please

fixed by adding this code in CustomFilter
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.equals("abc")) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication
                    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("dad","4343", new ArrayList<>());


(i add new ArrayList<>() to authenticate)
